# Can't jump into closure

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

I am trying to register but my code is not jumping into the closure

```
FireStoreManager.shared.register(user: user, password: password) { [weak self] result, error -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                guard let uid = result?.user.uid else {
                    print("Not user registed")
                    return
                }
            } else {
                completion(result, error)
                self?.registData(user: user, password: password, uid: result?.user.uid ?? "", fullname: fullname)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong capture list syntax. Your top line should look like:

```
FireStoreManager.shared.register(user: user, password: password) { [weak self] (result, error) in
```